# Installing the the new library mongodb c# driver

Tags: mongodb

Appeared a new version of library mongodb c# driver, but why when I install (latest version) do not installed library with GridFS ?
Anybody knows why ?

Thanks,

Comment: What's the question here? Please take your time to formulate a good question. Read the *"rules"* on how to ask questions on SO.

Comment: Sorry for the problem, I do not read the rules.
This library MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.dll doesn't exists after install.

Comment: If you're using NuGet, you need to separately install the MongoDB.Driver.GridFS package.